# is there a way to increment a loop by a power in parallel when using openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

```
int d = 0;
while (d < log2(n))
{
    #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + pow(2, d + 1))
        {
            ScanNumbers[i + pow(2, d + 1) - 1] = ScanNumbers[i + pow(2, d) - 1] + ScanNumbers[i + pow(2, d + 1) - 1];
        }
    PrintVector(ScanNumbers);
    d++;
}
```

ScanNumbers is a vector of ints.
n is the size of ScanNumbers

Comment: Side note: `pow` operates in floating point and returns numbers that are "Good Enough". Integers don't deal in "Good Enough" and you'll often find that the number that comes out gets truncated down to the wrong number. In the case of exponents of 2, use left shifting, ie `1 << d` and make sure `d` will specifies a number of bits that will fit in an `int`.

Comment: changed it to an int and it is working thanks a million ; )

Comment: You're trying to do some sort of a prefix sum. OpenMP actually has a `scan` operation. That might be easier than trying to code it out yourself.

Comment: can you link me to the openmp scan operation. I am very new to openmp so this would be a great help

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a constant inside the inner loop, so it can be replaced by a simple integer without having to call pow on every iteration.

```cpp
    while (n >> (d+1))  // d < log2(n)
    {
        const int d_pow = 1 << (d+1); // pow(2,d+1)
        #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + d_pow)
        {
            ScanNumbers[i + (1 << (d + 1)) - 1] = ScanNumbers[i + (1 << d) - 1] + ScanNumbers[i + (1 << (d + 1)) - 1];
        }
        PrintVector(ScanNumbers);
        d++;
    }
```

also don't use `log2` and `pow` for base2 arithmetic, as pointed by @user4581301 this causes inacuracy and it's also computationally expensive as opposed to shifts.

Edit: just added +1 to fix the integer math,

Answer (score 1):

```
while (d < log2(n))
{
#pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + (int)(pow(2, d + 1)))
    {
        ScanNumbers[i + pow(2, d + 1) - 1] = ScanNumbers[i + pow(2, d) - 1] + ScanNumbers[i + pow(2, d + 1) - 1];
    }
    
    PrintVector(ScanNumbers);
    d++;
}
```

Comment: The `(int)` cast gets it "working" but doesn't help against the hidden problem of the errors that can be introduced in the transformation of the `double` value to an `int` value. Here's a slightly different example: `pow(5,2)` should return 25, right? Sometimes the arcane math used by `pow`, because it also has to handle the really nasty cases like e to the power of pi, results in a returned value of 24.999999999999997. Close enough for a `double`, but as an integer that's 24.

Comment: @user4581301 the best thing about doubles is that they are always a power of 2, as he is just using pow and log2 to represent the powers of two he'll be fine, so long as `n` is less than the maximum number representable by the mantissa (2^52).

Comment: @AhmedAEK Agree in general, but you can't always count on it. 25 is also easily representable, but some implementations do `pow` (and `log`) the hard way and the damage is done in the computing rather than the representation. These days a smart implementation sees `pow(2,x)` and inserts the appropriate left-shift for you or has hidden tests to short circuit the extra work, but I find myself working with a lot of old and obscure tools and can't afford to smurf around.

Comment: @user4581301 a simple way to overcome that is to take the nearest integer, that is `(int)(pow(x,y)+0.5)` . This is I think always safe as long as the result doesn't overflow an `int`.